# php sequence multiply unable to get single digit

Tags: php

Following are the code:

```
<?php 

$a = array(2,3,5,7);


function check($n){
    $i=0, $s=0;
    while($n){
        $s += $n%10*a[$i++%4];
        $n /= 10;
    }

    return $s;
}

$n = "1234567890";
while($n > 9){
    $t = $n;
    $n = check($n);
    if (t==n)
        break;
}

echo "Answer = ". $n;




?>
```

Given a sequence of digits:
Multiply every 4th digit with "2" starting from first digit.
Multiply every 4th digit with "3" starting from second digit.
Multiply every 4th digit with "5" starting from third digit.
Multiply every 4th digit with "7" starting from fourth digit.
Sum all the 4 sets of output together.
Break down the sum into digit components and sum it up.
Continue reducing it to single digit.
The final digit is the check digit.

Example: "1234567890"
    1 => 1 * 2 = 2
    2 => 2 * 3 = 6
    3 => 3 * 5 = 15
    4 => 4 * 7 = 28
    5 => 5 * 2 = 10
    6 => 6 * 3 = 18
    7 => 7 * 5 = 35
    8 => 8 * 7 = 56
    9 => 9 * 2 = 18
    0 => 0 * 3 = 0

Sum = 2 + 6 + 15 + 28 + 10 + 18 + 35 + 56 + 18 + 0 = 188

188 break down to "1", "8", "8".
1 + 8 + 8 = 17
17 break down to "1", 7".
1 + 7 = 8

The check digit is "8".

What is the check digit for the value "75061812345"?

Comment: certainly it's NOT. I had a sequence which return double digit instead one.

Answer (score 1):

There's some questionable code in your sample...I'm not sure why its so confusing or what you are trying to achieve with it.

Anyway, iterate through your original number and multiply it by the correct value in the array.  Then just sum up the digits.

```
// Set your variables
$a = array(2,3,5,7);
$n = "1234567890";
$check = 0;

// Iterate the original number and multiply by correct multiplier
for($i=0;$i<strlen($n);$i++)
{
    $check += $n[$i] * $a[$i%4];
}

// Sum the digits if greater than or equal to 10 (i.e. more than 1 digit)
while($check >= 10)
{
    $check = array_sum(str_split($check));
}

// echo $check = 8
```